# PowerShell Экспорт SQL результата запроса в CSV

Tags: sql-server, csv, powershell

не понимаю что я делаю не так. У меня есть скрипт на PowerShell, он подключается к базе делает запрос и возвращает результат, данный результат  мне нужно сохранить в экселе и CSV

```
  $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=msdb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "Select * from MSdbms"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$DataAdapter = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $SqlCmd
$Dataset = new-object System.Data.Dataset
write-output $DataAdapter.Fill($Dataset) | Out-Null
$Output = $DataSet.Tables
$Output 

Export-Csv -InputObject $Output -Append -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\Users\users\TestScripts\Report.csv
```

Результат на экран выводится верный [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а вот в CSV выводится какая-то шляпа, не пойму где ошибка.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $query = "Select * from MSdbms"
    $connection = "Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=msdb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
    $report = "C:\Users\user\TestScripts\Report.csv" 
        
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query -ConnectionString $connection | Export-Csv -Delimiter ';' -Path $report -notypeinformation
```